# Create horizontal reference line in matlab

Tags: matlab

I tried to create  a horizontal reference line using refline

```
 hline = refline(0,0.);
    set(hline,'color','r');
    set(hline,'Marker','o');
    set(hline,'LineStyle','-');
```

This generates the desired refline except that the marker 'O' is set at the start point and end point only.
how can I have the entile horizontal refline to have the 'o'  marker?Am I missing something here.?

Comment: `refline` is not a standard MATLAB function, so we can't tell you how it works. Either way, if you set a `Marker` on a `line` object, it will set the marker type at every data point. So, if you create a straight line using two (x,y) pairs, you'll get two markers. You'll probably see in the `refline` implementation you have that it creates two data points.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a regular plot:

```
x = linspace(0,1,10);
y = zeros(size(x));
plot(x,y,'-or');
```